# Are there limitations on the size of a feature in a geopackage?

Tags: r, sf, geopackage

I have a big MULTIPOLYGON feature that I can manipulate in `sf`, but when I try to save it in a `Geopackage` file from `sf` I get the message:

`Failed to create feature 0 in T_POLIGONOS_HILUCS`

and then an error

```
Error in st_write.sf(..., quiet = quiet, append = append, delete_layer = delete_layer) : 
  failed writing to temporary file C:\Users\goerlich\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmCJqiq\fileca058a32e7e.gpkg
```

The big feature comes from a disolving operation, and I can save it before disolving, but not after.

I wonder if is there a limit on the size of a single feature, because according to the [OGC GeoPackage Encoding Standard](https://www.geopackage.org/spec120/index.html#_ogc_geopackage_encoding_standard)

> The maximum size of a GeoPackage file is about 140TB. In practice a lower size limit MAY be imposed by the filesystem to which the file is written. Many mobile devices require external memory cards to be formatted using the FAT32 file system which imposes a maximum size limit of 4GB.

And my feature is about 1GB.

Comment: It may not be a size but a complexity issue. There are several things to try: 1) do an st_buffer(0) to try and fix and invalid shapes, 2) do a st_buffer() by a very small non-zero amount to try and remove small, insignificant holes between dissolved shapes, 3) st_simplify() to smooth out complex edges, 4) and combination of 1, 2, and 3, though try to always put the st_buffer(0) last.

Comment: Are you able to save your feature in a different format to disk? What about saving to C:\ directly instead of your temp directory? Just to eliminate some other possible reasons for failing..

Comment: Options 1) and 2) of @Shawn doesn`t work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

After spliting the disolving in two features I´m able to save the file in `Geopackage` format without problems. No `Failed to create feature 0...` appears.

Since `GeoPackage` is a SQLite database and reviewing the limits: https://sqlite.org/limits.html, I think that I have exceeded the maximum length of a string, and this was the real problem, more than complexity.

See also an SE [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314500/does-geopackage-impose-a-maximum-number-of-non-geometry-columns-per-feature).